# How to make a strongly typed event emitters in my TypeScript class?

Tags: typescript, eventemitter

I'm trying to make a strongly typed event emitters in my TypeScript class, but I have some troubles.
I have 2 errors in the following code:

```
type AudioEvents = {
    "start": (title: string) => void,
    "stop": () => void
}

export class Audio {
    private _listeners: {
        [E in keyof AudioEvents]: Array<AudioEvents[E]>
    } = {
        "start": [],
        "stop": []
    };

    on<E extends keyof AudioEvents>(event: E, listener: AudioEvents[E]) {
        this._listeners[event].push(listener);
    }

    private emit<E extends keyof AudioEvents>(event: E, ...args: Parameters<AudioEvents[E]>) {
        this._listeners[event].forEach(listener => {
            listener(args);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the first error:

```
Argument of type 'AudioEvents[E]' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.
  Type '((title: string) => void) | (() => void)' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
    Type '(title: string) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.

            this._listeners[event].push(listener);
```

And here is the second:

```
Argument of type 'Parameters<AudioEvents[E]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type '[] | [title: string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type '[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

                listener(args)
```

I don't undersand why there are these errors but think it's a good way to do event emitters because my IDE like it:

- [emit method use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sd0Z.png)
- [on method use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sPCC.png)

I suppose that in fact these 2 errors are due to the same misunderstanding.
Do you have an idea to fix these errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Typescript has no dependent types.
See [Suggestion for Dependent-Type-Like Functions: Conservative Narrowing of Generic Indexed Access Result Type #33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014)

The issue described there is one-to-one mapping of your problem.

In your case, I would use a different function for each event:

```
type StartCallback = (title: string) => void;
type StopCallback = () => void;

export class Audio {
    private _startListeners: StartCallback[] = [];
    private _stopListeners: StopCallback[] = [];
    

    public onStart(listener: StartCallback) {
        this._startListeners.push(listener);
    }

    public onStop(listener: StopCallback) {
        this._stopListeners.push(listener);
    }

    private emitStart(title: string) {
        this._startListeners.forEach(listener => {
            listener(title);
        });
    }

    private emitStop() {
        this._stopListeners.forEach(listener => {
            listener();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And maybe like this ?
`type AudioEvents = { start: [string], stop: [] };` for the type declaration, 
`private _listeners: {[E in keyof AudioEvents]: Array<(...arg: AudioEvents[E]) => void>}` for the listener list attribute, 
`on<E extends keyof AudioEvents>(event: E, listener: (...arg: AudioEvents[E]) => void): void` for the `on()` definition and 
`private emit<E extends keyof AudioEvents>(event: E, ...args: AudioEvents[E]): void` for the `emit()` definition ?
I have still one error in `emit()` at the line `listener(args)`, but I think it's better, don't you think too ?

Comment: The error is `Argument of type 'AudioEvents[E]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type '[string] | []' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type '[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: 2 problems in your code: 1. the union is not narrowed down by the type of the event: `Type '[string] | []' is not assignable to type 'string'.` 2. You don't destructure the record
like listener(...args); and get `Type '[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`